# Can't get location on android device

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get current location in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443577/get-current-location-in-android)

I'm trying to make an application for android that gives me the position of the device.
I'm using the LocationManager.requestlocationupdates method to start a listener.
Unfortunately this doesn't work. When I'm looking for the stacktrace in Logcat I don't find any error but one sentence.

> 11-28 12:01:17.377: E/AndroidRuntime(1138):   at 
>   Tom.Tracer.App.GetCoords.run(GetCoords.java:28)

This line doesn't really help me further..

I'm using this code :

```
@Override
public void run() {
     lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) ;
     lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener) ; 


}
```

The Listener

```
private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        Date date = new Date(); 
        toSave = "NEW" + date.toString()+ "-" + location.getLatitude() + "-" + location.getLongitude() + "/";
        p("To save: " + toSave); 

        }
};
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443577/get-current-location-in-android

Comment: Put a try catch around your lm.requestLocationUpdates and see if the exception contains some usefull information.

Comment: you have set the correct permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to call the Looper.prepare() method .
Thanks for your comments!

Comment: mark question answered then.